# How to set up remote debugging on a machine without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Is there a way to set up Remote Debugging (Msvscom.exe) on a machine that does not have Visual Studio installed?

I would like to attach to the service running on the VM so I can debug an issue in the code. I've done this before but both machines have had VS installed.

The Dev box is running Visual Studio 2010/Windows 7. The VM is running Windows 7 without Visual Studio.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I'm going to resurrect this because anyone who's tried to do this knows it's a complete pain in the ass every time, and that it changes slightly with every possible combination of host/remote system you can have.

### Visual Studio Remote Tools Links:

1. [Visual Studio 2010 remote debugger.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=475) (Working as of 21/Oct/2016)
2. [Visual Studio 2013 remote tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44918) (working as of 21/Oct/2016)
3. [Visual Studio 2015 remote tools x86 - Direct download link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/c/8/9/c8986418-b5cb-4692-946e-a9f029c6d369/rtools_setup_x86.exe)
4. [Visual Studio 2015 remote tools x64 - Direct download link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/2/1225c23d-3599-48c9-a314-f7d631f43241/rtools_setup_x64.exe)
5. [Visual Studio Tools (Thanks Robo Burned)](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)
6. [Visual Studio 2017 Remote Tools x64 - Direct download link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746570&clcid=0x409) ([Thanks Isaac Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185395/1518546))
7. [Visual Studio 2017 Remote Tools x86 - Direct download link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746569&clcid=0x409) ([Thanks Isaac Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185395/1518546))
8. [Visual Studio 2019 Remote Tools - download link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)

***This is the setup I succeeded with today:***

**Host (Dev) Machine:**
Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64. Running Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4.

**Remote Machine:**
Industrial/Factory Floor PC running Windows Embedded Standard 32-bit. It looks/feels exactly like Windows 7. Running SP1. Visual Studio is not installed. Has the .NET framework 4.

**Network:**
Both machines are on the same subnet. I access the remote machine via RDP and run my application that way.

**Microsoft-Proprietary Follicle-Deterioration Implementation:**
Make note of your dev machine's user name and password. For some reason you have to create exactly the same user name and password on the remote machine. Because Microsoft.

**How I did it:**
I downloaded the Visual Studio 2010 remote debugger from the link provided by @sJhonny. I had to switch off of Visual Studio 2013 in that article and over to 2010. If you care to go over the 2010 article with a fine-tooth comb to find the download, the link is right next to the "No one ever finds this helpful" link at the top. If not, just follow my link above.

Install that on the remote machine and run the configuration wizard. I left the defaults for the wizard:

- "Run the 'Visual Studio ....." was checked off
- Username is LocalSystem and password is blank
- Allow only computers on the local network....

Run the Remote Debugger on the remote system and you'll see

> Msvsmon started a new server named 'username@machinename...'

in the interface. So far so good. Run the application on the remote machine. On the dev machine, Ctrl+Alt+P in visual studio will open "Attach to Process" (It's also under the tools menu). I got a popup about my dev machine's firewall not being configured properly and was asked if I wanted to allow the connections etc... Say yes obviously.

Enter the 'username@machinename' combination into the qualifier box... press Refresh and pray a little. Pray a little more a lot harder and you should see a list of the processes running on the remote machine. Select your process and attach to it.

***But my breakpoints don't work!?*** Of course they don't... because using the breakpoints in the same directory as the application on the remote machine would make too much sense. If you were lucky enough, you got warned about a breakpoint cache and got shown a dialog with a path.

The dialog mentions something about it being correct relative to the remote machine. It's lying. It has nothing to do with the remote machine except that it forced you to create a brand new user over there with the same name as your current user because Microsoft. To get your breakpoints to work, follow the path on your dev machine (customizable in Tools>Options>Debugging>Symbols: Cache symbols in this directory) and copy your application's .pdb files over to that directory. You have to copy them over with every new build, unless there's an option to do it automatically; I haven't checked because I have yet to stop celebrating my remote debugging success.

Everything should work now.

Comment: Link for VS2015 is broken

Comment: "Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015" is now available under collapsible area "Tools for Visual Studio 2015" on  https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: Awsome! Thank you for this, technically brilliant step-by-step descriptions (and I also like the irony since I made similar experiences ... ;-)   One more hint: You can use [this link @ microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) for the remote tools and select "Other Versions" if you require to download older versions. So you just need one link (bookmark) for all.

Comment: Because Microsoft ... the link above is valid, but I just noticed that for **Visual Studio 2915 Update 3** you need a different link: [https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2015-update-3](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2015-update-3) (scroll down until you find **Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** on the left side)

Comment: Regarding debugging you wrote: You have to copy them over with every new build ... right, that's cumbersome, and I would prefer to have the .PDBs in the same directory with the binaries - but to do this automatically you can create a post-build action for this.

Comment: @Matt Yes, you can create a post-build but you'll run into problems if your solution is under source control and you accidentally commit it. Build server explosions etc....

Comment: Good point. I created it outside of the mapped folder so you can't accidently check it in.

Comment: One more question - have you ever set up remote debugging in a cross-domain environment (e.g. your PC being in one domain, the web server being in a different - test - domain)? I didn't find the host on which the remote debugging tool was running. Do you have a hint, maybe? I was using a Windows account as debug user and don't want to turn of authentication.

Comment: I've tried to do it a few times but was never successful. You need to be able to see (ping etc...) the debug target from your development machine. I've learned more about remote debugging since I posted the answer but haven't had time to update. The most important part is the authentication to the target. In my experience (and someone can correct this statement) if your credentials don't match *exactly* you're just not getting in. Ever. You need to find a way to impersonate your user on the remote domain. There's probably some additional setup you can do somehow that I don't know of.

Comment: I learned that the 2015 tools listen on port 4020 and VS17 connects to 4022. Are there even tools for 2017? Could not find them.

Comment: I'm not sure... 2017 is new so possibly they haven't been released? I unfortunately don't work in Visual Studio anymore so my knowledge will be stale.

Comment: Just want to add my experience. In my qualifier field, I was never able to Find successfully. Instead I put in the computer IP and port and pressed Refresh. Also, you have to use the remote debugging tool that exactly matches the VS version on your dev machine. It seems like there is no backwards compatibility.

Comment: Also, the remote tools for VS2017 are located here https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ under Tools for Visual Studio 2017

Comment: One more comment, I just tested this and I didn't have to make a user account on my remote machine. The usernames could be different. I'm on Windows 7 both machines and have VS 2012 update 3.

Comment: How to attach to remote Windows Service, not Process/Application.
The above method works but only lists processes, I need to attach to service or application which shows in task manager.

Comment: @Koder101 There should be a checkbox for "Show processes from all users". Click that.

Comment: What if I'm using dotnetcore on linux? how do I debug?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I'm not sure. I haven't used DotNetCore yet. I'd check if there's any documentation

Comment: I followed @Brandon 's process more or less and got it to work. Having the target system run the exe *remotely* from the dev system was the instruction I must have missed that got it to work.

Answer (score 19):

certainly there is.
You can install msvsmon without installing visual studio.
I've done this myself on several machines.
the tricky part lays in authorization- the user running VS on your local machine needs special priviliges on the remote machine.
ms has some articles explaining the details- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx,

Comment: Thanks sJhonny,can I simply copy over the MSVCMON.exe to the VM machine?

Comment: don't remember really... i'm sure the article i've linked to / one of the related articles at the bottom has the answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Update:
Here's the links for 2017 which are not obvious to find either.

[Visual Studio Remote Tools Links x64 direct link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746570&clcid=0x409)

[Visual Studio Remote Tools Links x86 direct link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746569&clcid=0x409)

Answer (score 3):

Taken from:
[how-to-implement-remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/910448/how-to-implement-remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-2005)

> Let's consider an example to understand this situation clearly. Molly
>      Clark and Adam Barr are both employees at Adventure Works. Adventure
>      Works has a Microsoft Windows NT domain named adventure-works.com.
>      Adam is having trouble with some software that Molly wrote. Molly
>      would like to debug this software on Adam's computer. Molly and Adam
>      follow these steps:
>
> - Adam doesn't have the remote debugger on his computer. To set up the remote debugger, Molly decides to share out the Program
>     Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger directory
>     on her computer. She creates a file share called Remote.
> - Adam runs \MollyComputerName\Remote\x86\Msvsmon.exe.
> - After the remote debugger starts, Adam clicks Permissions on the Tools menu to configure the remote debugger by using the Permissions
>     dialog box. He gives Molly permission to debug.
>     **Note** Adam could also configure the remote debugger by passing the /allow option when the remote debugger starts.
> - Molly starts Visual Studio 2005.
> - To open the Attach to Process dialog box, Molly clicks Attach to Process on the Tools menu.
> - Molly connects to Adam's computer by entering adventure-works.com\Adam@AdamComputerName in the Qualifier box.
> - Under Available Processes, Molly selects the worker process that her application is using and then clicks Attach.
> - Molly opens a browser and provides the URL to the remote application. The execution stops where the breakpoint is placed in
>     the application.

Answer (score 2):

There's also another way which I prefer (if you have fast internet connection).

You don't have to download or install anything on remote desktop connection.

1. You can share your disk `C:` while connecting via Remote Desktop Connection.

   [image: Remote Dekstop - Share Local Resources]
2. On the remote desktop go to location (depending on your local location)

   ```
   \\tsclient\C\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64
   ```
3. (optional) Create shortcut to folder or msvsmon.exe on desktop
4. Run it remotely from your local disk via shared disk. (start can take few seconds depending on your connection quality)

Option2: Copy Remote Debugger\x64  or x86 folder to the remote location and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with asp.net core 2.1, the only difference from the answers above was that the process you attach to is dotnet.exe.