# visual studio remote debugging - can't find the computer in the same domain

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I've installed Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 on a remote computer in the same domain.
I can ping and telnet connection to the defined  port.

I'm trying to find the server when I open the "attached to process" dialog and the VS doesn't find it. 
(I tried entering both its IP and Name)

Any idea?

Comment: Related post - [How to setup remote debugging on a machine without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586500/465053)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I faced same issue. I was pressing on "Find..." button and there searching for the computer, that always gave me "Found 0 connection". It looks like a VS2012 bug.

However when I've entered computer name (IP address also worked for me) and port in the "Qualifier" field and then **pressed "Refresh" button** far below - only then the connection was established and the list of processes was displayed.

The format of the text in the "Qualifier" field was `COMPUTER-NAME:PORT` (e.g. `WIN2012-TEST:4016`) as well as `IP-ADDRESS:PORT` (e.g. `192.168.1.1:4016`), both worked. The port was the one that is displayed in the Tools -> Options of the Remote Debugging Monitor running on the target machine.

Comment: Thank you! In addition, I would like to mention that the filter in the "Find..." window looks like local subnet only filter, i.e even if you write in this window IP-ADDRESS:PORT of the remote machine it will not try to find it.

Comment: Instead of Find button, use refresh after typing IP address

Comment: This was the trick "Instead of Find button, use refresh after typing IP address"

Comment: Thank you very much!
I had to turn off the auto-refresh flag. As soon as I refreshed manually, I was able to enter the remote server user name and password then connect!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message, but ended up finding that it was a different issue that the one OP encountered.

My problem was that remote debugging tools are *not* cross-version-compatible (at least to some extent).  In my case, VS 2013 could not connect to the 2015 Remote Debugging tools.  I admit, I kind of expected it to work, but I'm not terribly surprised.  It wasn't until I explicitly typed in the machine and port that I received an actionable error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same option, neither the Find button nor the Refresh button could help me (Visual Studio 2013 and remote debugging 2013), I even tried computer name and IP address with port. 
It worked out when I selected "Show processes from all users" and it loaded All processes.

I guess there's a delay with this tool and you might need to do some work around to fix this.