# Remote deploy/debug Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2017

How can I set up remote deploy + debugging in VS2017 using a net core app which targets net framework?

I have the remote tools installed and working on my target device. I can connect to it and debug remote applications.

I have a build configuration set to build my application to a remote share on my target machine.

How can I get VS to launch this on the remote machine then attach debugger?

Comment: Related post - [How to setup remote debugging on a machine without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586500/465053)

Answer (score 29):

1. On your remote machine, go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2017 to download and install the remote debugging tools.
2. Run the "Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger" application you just installed
3. The app will show you the servername and port in the main window; something like 'COMPUTERNAME:4022'
4. In Visual Studio on your development machine, choose "Remote Machine" as the run target. This should bring up a dialog box to enter in the remote machine information.
5. If you see your machine listed under "Auto Detected", select it. If not, use the servername and port you found in step 3 in the manual section.
6. You should be able to "hit play" with "Remote Machine" selected and it will deploy the app to the remote machine and allow you to debug (it may ask for a username and password to the remote machine).

Comment: Thanks, the link is working. There are some dead links around the internet for remote debugging tools.

Comment: You lost me at step 4. Where are the options you're talking about?

Comment: @Nickdb93 press Ctrl+Alt+P to open the Attach To Process dialog

Comment: @Nickdb93 go to your project properties and find the "Debug" settings, there is a checkbox there that allows you to select "Use remote machine".

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Such a checkbox does not exist for .NET Core projects.

Comment: Same problem as @Ray. Can't find the checkbox in .NET Core project.

Answer (score 6):

Head to this page:
https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Find the Tools for Visual Studio 2017 section downloads
and download the Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2017 version for your server

After installation completes, launch Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger and configure port for it, you also need to configure your endpoints to your server.

Next step, go to your computer(Visual Studio 2017), On Debug Menu, click to attach the debugger to process. Enter your server and port (server.com:port) and refresh the list of process, it will require user and password, mark Show process from all users. Find w3wp.exe and attach to it.

More Complete information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't answer my question! I want to automate remote deploy and debug!

Comment: w3wp.exe is for IIS. There was no mention of IIS in the question.

Comment: Just a bit of an update, I was only able to download the remote debugging tools for 2017 because I have an Enterprise license through my company. A real pain. If this tool is part of that license, they should say that. Otherwise, it should be in an open area where anybody can get to it.

Answer (score 0):

New download-links (VS 2017 download no longer available on visualstudio.com):

Overview of all VS downloads:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019

Direct download of VS 2017 Remote Tool (require MS login):
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=remote%20tools%20visual%20studio%202017